# What is used for a 2D board in functional programming with Scala

Tags: arrays, scala, list, functional-programming

I'm creating the [isolation board game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(board_game)) in functional programming with Scala.
So obviously I need some sort of a 2D board. The problem is I don't know what should I use : an Array of array (which is mutable) or a list of a list (immutable) knowing that I would want a Any type.
I saw that we can get an array of defined dimensions and type with `val board = Array.ofDim[Any](rows, cols)`. I can't find anything like that with lists. However, in functional programming, is it not better to use a immutable collection ?

Any suggestions ?

Comment: I think arrays will better suit your case because they allow fast random access and you will probably need to get elements of a certain index. In lists, random access is slower. If you want immutable collection backed by an array internally please check [ArraySeq](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/ArraySeq.html), which was added with **Scala 2.13**.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look into ArraySeq which seems well suited for what I want to achieve. However, is it allowed in functional programming ?

Comment: *ArraySeq* is an immutable data structure, so it suits very well with functional programming paradigm.

Comment: So it's possible to create an 2D ArraySeq ? Will it be an ArraySeq of ArraySeq or a ArraySeq of Array ?

Answer (score 0):

In scala list - is a linked list data structure. And conceptually you don't know about content of some list. In functional programming you shouldn't use variables as *named cells* in memory. You should use functions to get what you need. So, you can define list with default values of needed capacity, but you can use method fill in List:

```
val board = List.fill(rows)(List.fill(cols)('${default_value}'))
```

replace `default_value` on some value. The type of board will be `List[List[default_value_type]]`

or you can use Vector[Vector[T]] for board. Vector is immutable data structure with random access and update by index function. Just look at `apply()` and `update()` - functions.

for ArraySeq you can create ArraySeq of ArraySeqs with some values:

```
val board: ArraySeq[ArraySeq[Boolean]] = ArraySeq((0 to rows).map(_ => ArraySeq((0 to cols).map(_ => false):_*)):_*)
```

or same fill function like in list:

```
val board: ArraySeq[ArraySeq[Boolean]] = ArraySeq.fill(rows)(ArraySeq.fill(cols)(false))
```

Comment: And what do you think of ArraySeq which is immutable as mentioned by @krzysztof-atłasik  ?

Comment: Sorry, I mistaken, Vector is immutable like an ArraySeq. I think you can use any of them. They both have updated and apply methods.